# Cabeçalhos de cache HTTP em Servlets

Tags: java, servlet, cache

Gostaria de saber se existem bibliotecas ou soluções para tratar *requests* contendo cabeçalhos como `Last-Modified`, `If-Modified-Since`, `If-Range` (para resumo de downloads), `If-None-Match`, `Cache-Control`, `Pragma`, etc e produzir respostas com código `304`, [ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag), `Expires`, `Last-Modified`, `Content-Range`, etc em Servlets.

Enquanto sei que esses cabeçalhos de *cache* e controle de download são mais relevantes para recursos estáticos, esbarrei em uma situação (que julgo ser bastante comum) em que o suporte à esses cabeçalhos aumenta a *performance* e diminui custos de uma aplicação.

No meu caso específico, estou construindo uma aplicação *open-source* para criação de colagens no Facebook junto a um colega (segue link caso seja relevante: http://sfcb.7rtc.com). Essa aplicação está hospedada no [GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) que [impõe limites e cobra por requests externos](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#UrlFetch).

No nosso caso codificamos um Servlet que age como Proxy e redimensionador de imagens do Facebook (link: [ProxyServlet](https://bitbucket.org/7RTC/sfcb/src/081c14375ccc2306755c201f3ed025b0edce0657/src/main/java/br/com/javamagazine/sfcb/servlets/ProxyServlet.java?at=master)). O *proxy* é necessário para contornar [exceções de segurança na hora de exportar o conteúdo do Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390232/why-does-canvas-todataurl-throw-a-security-exception) relacionadas à [Política da mesma origem](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_de_mesma_origem) uma vez que os servidores de recursos estáticos do Facebook não implementam cabeçalhos [CORS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Nesse caso do proxy pudemos simplesmente delegar os *headers* do *request* do Servlet para o Facebook:

```java
public static final ImmutableSet<String> excludedHeaders = 
    ImmutableSet.of("Cookie", "Host");

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    final HttpURLConnection connection;
    try {
       // código para abrir o request
       final Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
       while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
           final String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
           final String headerValue = request.getHeader(headerName);

           if (!excludedHeaders.contains(headerName)) {
               log.info(headerName + " : " + headerValue);
               connection.setRequestProperty(headerName, headerValue);
           }
       }
    }
    // Restante do código
}
```

E copiar os *headers* e código de status da resposta do Facebook de volta para o Servlet.

```java
final int httpCode = connection.getResponseCode();
response.setStatus(httpCode);
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : connection.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
    final String header = entry.getKey();
    log.info(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
    for (String headerValue : entry.getValue()) {
        response.addHeader(header, headerValue);
    }
}
// Código para tratar o corpo da resposta, e em caso de status 200, redimensioná-la.
```

Isso foi suficiente para tornar a aplicação mais responsiva e aliviar muito a quantidade de *requests* externos (imagens repetidas são cacheadas no *browser* e *requests* consecutivos não batem no Servlet).

Porém, não considero essa uma solução completa ou genérica (uma vez que é específica para servlets de proxy).

Na Stack Overflow em inglês encontrei referências ao [FileServlet](http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html) bo [BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/) que implementa de maneira bastante completa a questão de Servlets para downloads locais (o código dele trata todos os cabeçalhos mencionados "na unha", além de suportar [compressão GZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression)).

Mas fiquei imaginando se não existe uma biblioteca ou solução mais genérica para tratar esse tipo de problema (por exemplo, com o uso de [filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) e / ou uma API simplificada para abstrair detalhes de implementação).

Alguém já ouviu falar de algo assim? (E se não, alguém se candidata a começar a escrever algo assim? :D).

Comment: Sempre que precisei destes headers, fiz o trabalho na unha a partir do `HttpServletRequest`. Como na prática os headers dentro dele são apenas um `Map` bem simples e cada um destes headers tem valores simples e pré-definidos (com exeção do ETag que é um pouquinho mais complicadinho), acho que ninguém se deu muito o trabalho de se preocupar em deixar as coisas um pouco mais doces e abstraídas para os programadores.

Comment: Revisitando a questão agora, tenho visto vários casos diferentes e problemas relacionados a headers, CDNs e caching. Talvez devido às muitas variedades de aplicações, à utilização específica que elas fazem do protocolo HTTP e às limitações dos próprios CDNs, muita gente acaba por implementar soluções customizadas. Por exemplo, o Cloud Front da Amazon não suporta compressão GZIP *on-the-fly* de recursos armazenados no S3. A solução é usar um proxy com nginx para interceptar as requisições.

Comment: Infelizmente, não existem (ou desconheço) soluções canônicas para caching, ainda mais em Java. Portanto seria difícil pensar em uma solução genérica melhor que a apresentada na questão. Mas é um tema promissor e importante, com muito a ser explorado, que precisa de inovação principalmente num mundo onde cada milissegundo é uma preocupação.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe a biblioteca [**Java EE Cache Filter**](https://github.com/samaxes/javaee-cache-filter), que consiste num conjunto de filtros para manipulação de cabeçalhos.

Como os filtros podem ser mapeados via `web.xml`, acredito que não deve haver muita dificuldade em sua aplicação.

O filtro para adicionar o cache é o [`CacheFilter`](https://github.com/samaxes/javaee-cache-filter/wiki/CacheFilter). Veja um exemplo de uso:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>imagesCache</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.samaxes.filter.CacheFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>static</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>expirationTime</param-name>
        <param-value>2592000</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>imagesCache</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/img/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

***Nota**: pessoalmente eu não realizei testes com essa biblioteca para averiguar os detalhes do seu funcionamento. Porém acredito que a solução usando filtros é adequada.*

Por outro lado, dependendo do volume de dados, talvez seja necessário usar um serviço mais especializado como o [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/pt/s3/) ou [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/features-cdn). Nesse cenário, você alimenta o serviço com as imagens e ele se responsabiliza por redimensioná-la e distribuí-la de forma rápida, eficiente e com cache configurável.

Comment: Oi Luiz, seu google mojo é melhor que o meu hehehe. Quando a disponibilização de recursos estáticos, o GAE possui tratamente específico para eles e responde naturalmente bem a requests distribuídos, servindo os arquivos próximo à origem do Request (muita gente usa o GAE como uma espécie de poor man's [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)). Quanto a biblioteca, ela parece fazer o básico (expires, cache-control, cache privado e cache público) mas pode servir de ponto de partida para algo mais genérico! Obrigado.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly *"seu google mojo é melhor que o meu"* + *"poor man's CDN"*... ri muito! Bem, só espero ter ajudado, infelizmente parece que não haver uma biblioteca madura e **aberta** com essas funcionalidades.